# Most effective way to get collection of Elements with data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an approach to attach functionality to HTML code with custom data attributes like

```
<div data-prefix-f1="..." data-prefix-f2="..."></div>
```

Now I'd like to list all Elements having `dataset`, or better those having `data-prefix-*` attribute. My current approach is

```
<div data-prefix data-prefix-f1="..." data-prefix-f2="..."></div>
<script>
    container.querySelectorAll('[data-prefix]').forEach(el => /* examine el.dataset */)
</script>
```

But I'd like to have the HTML source as lean as possible and the empty `data-prefix` is kind of redundant and the code less readable. On the other hand, looping and examining ALL elements would be too expensive overhead. Any idea to effectively iterate Elements having `data-prefix-*` attributes?

Comment: If you want lean HTML, don't put that sort of data in the HTML - do it in the JavaScript instead. Gotta choose one.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'd like to have it declarative way and not to separate the data from the HTML code.

Comment: If you want the data in the HTML markup, then yes, the HTML markup will contain some bloat

Comment: I don't think wildcards can be used for attribute names, only attribute values

Comment: Are you by any chance referring to `[data-prefix]^`? This selects all elements which have an attribute whose name begins with `[data-prefix]`.

Comment: @JackFleeting is this specified somewhere? I got just *'[data-prefix]^' is not a valid selector* error in console.

Comment: @JanTuroň You're right and I misspoke; unfortunately, that selector selects the elements with a (known) attribute name whose attribute **value** starts with whatever, not those attributes whose **name** starts with whatever. You may have to use xpath (`Document.evaluate()`") instead.